# Selenium-webdriver errors

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

One of the error codes I am getting is this I don't really understand why I am getting it
(vs code py 3.9.1)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\jtwwi\Test1.py", line 3, in <module>     api = webdriver.Firefox() ``
```

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver

api = webdriver.Firefox()
api.get("https://www.youtube.com")
elem = api.find_elements_by_id("search")[1]
elem.send_keys("Your Search")
elem.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`api` is a *keyword* and you need to replace it with some other variable name. As an example:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```